# Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined when using two charts

Tags: javascript, function, charts, highcharts

I am displaying two Highcharts on the same page based on different data sets.

I am trying to apply a common function to both of them.

The common function that I am using in both charts is given below:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'getClipBox', function(proceed, animation, finalBox) {
        var result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        if (finalBox) {
            return {
                x: 0,
                width: this.chart.plotWidth
            }
        }

        return result;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

The way I am using the fuction is that I have created two script tags on the same page under which the two charts' data is processed.

Like the following:

**Chart 1:**

```
<script>
(function(H) {

    //The Above Code

    }(Highcharts));

    var chart = Highcharts.chart('ecg', {

    // the Chart Code
});

var delay = drawAnimationDuration / chart.plotWidth * chart.plotSizeX;

</script>
```

**Chart2:**

```
<script>
(function(H) {

    //The Same code Above

    }(Highcharts));

    var chart = Highcharts.chart('ppg', {

    // the 2nd Chart Code
});

var delay = drawAnimationDuration / chart.plotWidth * chart.plotSizeX;

</script>
```

**Note:** `drawAnimation` variable is defined for both the Charts.

The first chart is working fine, but the second chart is throwing the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined
>       at Object.success (:211:38)

Which redirects to this line above:

```
var delay = drawAnimationDuration / chart.plotWidth * chart.plotSizeX;
```

I have added a fiddle also. The fiddle is showing no data, but if I remove the function and run the functions directly, then it works.
**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/4terfoup/14/

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Have you tried to debug why this error occurs?

Comment: As far as I understand. The problem is in the function(H). I am calling it twice but it rus only once and then @WojciechChmiel

Comment: @AbnitChauhan could you create a fiddle with your charts?

Comment: Ok I will update you when I create the Fiddle @Mat.Now

Comment: Here is my JS Fiddle If I remove the functions its running smooth. whereas on enclosing the code under function it's not doing anything.
https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/4terfoup/14/

@Mat.Now

Comment: Here is the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/4terfoup/14/
@WojciechChmiel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a big mistake, you have to know what scope is in javascript, and how and where variables `are visible` in code. A quick guide to what scope is in JS:

```
let data = 'Example variable';
function firstFunction(){
  let nextVariable;

  //Here you can access to data and nextVariable
}

function firstFunction(){
  let thirdVariable;

  //Here you can access to data and thirdVariable
}

//But here in our global scope we only have access to the data variable because nextVariable and thirdVariable are in their own local scopes and you can't access them in the outside scope.
```

And in your example you have the same problem. You have defined `chart` and `drawAnimationDuration` only in the `ecgData` function so the `ppgData` function doesn't have access to these variables.

A working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zbdga4r6/

Comment: Ohh such a silly mistake. I totally forgot the ```chart`` variable missing from the ppgData function and ecgData function. BTW thats solves the problem. Thanks.